# Error: cordova platform add android

Tags: android, cordova, npm, phonegap-build

I'm using command line for `PhoneGap` and after that I created the project I want to add platform. When I digit this: cordova platform add android, I have this error:

```
> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.1
> TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
>     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:73:11)
>     at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
>     at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\np
> m\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\re
> quest\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:117:25)
>     at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_mod
> ules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:184:41)
>     at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\
> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\requ
> est\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:80:8)
>     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
>     at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
>     at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15)
>     at Request.start (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
> \cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js
> :594:30)
>     at Request.end (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
> ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:1
> 186:28)
```

Can I fix it??? I set my proxy and the version of Android is `4.4W.2 (API 20)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to the proxy, in [this issue of ionic-cli](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/321) people say downgrading node to `0.10.29` solves it.

Also, if downgrade is not an option, you can change the tunnel agent following this steps:

- Replace the content of C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent with the content of this zip: https://github.com/mikeal/tunnel-agent
- Configure the proxy settings:

  ```
  npm config set proxy http://proxy:port
  set PROXY=http://proxy:port
  ```

Comment: I think that the problem is the version of node.js...I use v0.12.2...How can I downgrading node to 0.10.29??? Another I set my proxy in right way...

Comment: C:\Users\BlaBla>npm -v
2.7.4

Comment: C:\Users\BlaBla>node -v
v0.12.2

Comment: Download from the official node repository and install it the usual way: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.29/